# Pass an email address to the SendObject method in VBA

Tags: email, vba, ms-access-2007

I would like to take the email address from my table 'GetContact_TempTbl" and send the report to that email address. This email will change according the company that recieves. I currently pull the related email address and store it in the temporary table. I currently get the Object Required error.

Many thanks in advace for the advice.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim stRecipients As String
Dim stDocName As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("GetContact_TempTbl")
Set stRecipients = rs.Fields("Contact_Email")
stDocName = "License CODs"
stRecipietns = stRecipients

DoCmd.SendObject acReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, stRecipients, , , "Thank You for your purchase"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your recordset holds one row for each recipient you want to email, walk the recordset to gather them instead of reading only the recipient from the first row.

```vb
Const stDocName As String = "License CODs"
Dim db As DAO.database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim stRecipients As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("GetContact_TempTbl")
With rs
    Do While Not .EOF
        stRecipients = stRecipients & ";" & !Contact_Email
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With

If Len(stRecipients) > 0 Then
    ' discard leading ";"
    stRecipients = Mid(stRecipients, 2)
    DoCmd.SendObject acReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, _
        stRecipients, , , "Thank You for your purchase"
Else
    MsgBox "No recipients to email!"
End If

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

However, if my interpretation was incorrect, and the recordset always contains a single row with just one `Contact_Email`, you don't even need a recordset.  You can simply retrieve the `Contact_Email` with `DLookup`.

```
stRecipients = Nz(DLookup("Contact_Email", "GetContact_TempTbl"), "")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only use `set` with an object, not a string:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim stRecipients As String
Dim stDocName As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("GetContact_TempTbl")
''This is not a field object, it is a string
stRecipients = rs.Fields("Contact_Email")
stDocName = "License CODs"
stRecipietns = stRecipients

DoCmd.SendObject acReport, stDocName, acFormatPDF, _
   stRecipients, , , "Thank You for your purchase"
```

It may be possible to make this easier if you say how you create the temporary table.